# axis java web service jsoup java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/nodes/Document

Tags: java, web-services, jsoup, axis, noclassdeffounderror

I'm developing an axis java web service using jsoup.

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

When I import org.jsoup.nodes.Document axis returns a NoClassDefFoundError exception.

I imported the jsoup jar correctly (the service alone works properly) but axis doesn't get the Document class.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: too less information to answer. Try yourself by following this - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when you use an external jar in your java project you have to add it in the axis lib folder (path: /web_server_local_folder/axis/WEB-INF/lib). 
I resolved my issue adding the jsoup jar in that folder.